# Taking a DateTime value and only accepting time and vice versa

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm currently developing an application to function as a todo - list and i was wondering how do i accept a Value from a date time box, but only use the value of the date, or the value of the time. I'm currently doing it like this.

```
DateTime ted = appointmentDateTimeDate.Value; //The date
DateTime at = appointmentDateTimeTime.Value;  //The time
```

should i be doing this another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property for date, and [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) for time:

```
DateTime ted = appointmentDateTimeDate.Date; //The date
TimeSpan at = appointmentDateTimeTime.TimeOfDay;  //The time
```

Comment: I just checked it should be

TimeSpan at = appointmentDateTimeTime.Value.TimeOfDay;

thanks very much though

Answer (score 1):

The BCL doesn't really separate dates and times nicely.

If you're happy to take a new external dependency, I'd like to plug my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library, which will let you separate things out clearly into `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`. To perform the conversion from a date/time picker you'd probably use:

```
var dateAndTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(appointmentDateTimeDate.Value);
LocalDate date = dateAndTime.LocalDate;
LocalTime time = dateAndTime.LocalTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime value ALWAYS contains both the date and the time, whether you use both or not.

You can use the .[Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of  a DateTime to get "just the date".  it will still have a time value, but the time value will be midnight.  You can also use the .[TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) property to get the time portion, which will be a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) indicating the number of ticks since midnight.

I'm taking a leap here and assuming you're trying to set the date with one control an d the time with another in the UI.  Here's a sample of some code we use to do this using an Ajax CalendarExtender attached to a textbox and [a custom TimePicker control](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=3221).

```
    DateTime dt;
    try
    {
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtViewDate.Text).AddHours(txtViewTime.Hour).AddMinutes(txtViewTime.Minute);
        if (txtViewTime.AmPm == MKB.TimePicker.TimeSelector.AmPmSpec.PM)
        {
            dt = dt.AddHours(12);
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString());

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // abort processing
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others pointed out a `DateTime` always has both a date and a time component. So although it's possible to save both independently using two `DateTime`, in most cases it's recommendable to save both together in a single `DateTime` instance.

You should see if you really need both values separated or if your application could combine both in one property, which will make things easier.

Comment: I'm using an inherited structure in which the base class holds the date and the child class holds the time. So i'm forced to do it this way, not by choice this is a university assignment.